# ¿Cómo extender Marked para soportar colores en sintaxis?

Tags: javascript, markdown

Me gustaría poder modificar este [script](https://unpkg.com/marked) basado en Markdown para poder darle color al texto. O sea, que después de cierto carácter, añadir ya sea el nombre del color o su código hexadecimal.

Algo más o menos así:

```
 *{red}hola*
 *{#f00}hola*
```

Aquí esta la página oficial del script [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que no puedas usar `<font color="#f00">*hola*</font>` para ello? Cambiar el parser haría necesidad de reimplementarlo todo, cuando Markdown ya provee tal característica.

Comment: El primer link está caido.

Comment: Es que estoy restringiendo el uso de html, por seguridad. Osea quiero hacer un sistema de comentarios pero permitiendo solo el uso del markdown. Pero me gustaría poder añadir esa opción.

Comment: Perdón @Error404 puse mal el link, pero ya lo corregí.

Comment: @AnimationsNow ¿A que te refieres con restringiendo el html por seguridad? Realmente el html se lo van a poder descargar y modificar. Las validaciones las tendrías que realizar siempre en el lado del servidor.

Comment: Si lo se, y a lo que me refiero sobre seguridad. Es evitar los ataques xss, por eso hago uso de markdown. Sobre PHP ya se como resolverlo, siendo sincero se mas PHP que javascript. Javascript es complicado. xD Y pues me gustaría que el sistema de comentarios sea dinámico, osea que muestre una vista previa antes y después de comentar.

Comment: Lo que pides esta lejos de ser algo trivial. Es implementar una funcionalidad nueva en una librería, que además [escapa de los estándares para los cuales fue diseñado markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). Quizás tengas más suerte consultando en la sección de [issues](https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/new) de la librería, ya que obviamente los mismos desarrolladores saben como funciona su propia librería.

Comment: Si ya lo se, y pues eso es lo que voy a hacer.

Comment: Por sierto, registrarse en github.com es gratis o de paga. Por que solo tegistrandome, podría recomendarles esa opción

Comment: Registrarse es gratis, se paga si deseas repositorios privados. Una [idea](https://github.com/chjj/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js#L450-L464) de lo necesario a cambiar para lograr tu idea. De recomendación filtra todo HTML que no desees en el servidor.

Comment: Ok gracias. Y si eso ya lo tenia entendido.