# Detectar texto entre llaves abiertas y cerradas en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Cómo puedo detectar cuándo una llave `{` se abre y cuándo se cierra `}`?
Lo que quiero lograr es detectar la apertura y el cierre de las llaves, pero también me gustaría poder detectar contenido dentro de ellas.

**Ejemplo:**

```
{#f66} o {red}
```

**Resultado esperado:**

1. Las llaves: `{#f66}` y `{red}`.
2. Y el contenido: `#f66` y `red`.

Comment: Lo que quiero es lograr esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35437/cómo-extender-marked-para-soportar-colores-en-sintaxis

Comment: Quiero darle color al texto usando markdown, ya sea en cursiva, negrita, tachado, etc. Usando un sintaxis así: `*{color} texto*`

Comment: Quiero darle color al texto, ya sea usando el código hexadecimal o el nombre del color. Eso es lo que quiero dar a entender.

Comment: Para empezar el sitaxis seria algo así: `*{red} texto*` y se imprimiría así: `<i style="color:red">texto</i>`. Lo quiero es impedir el uso de html en mis comentarios, pero permitir el uso de markdown, solo quiero poder añadirle la opción de darle color al texto, para que sea mas llamativo.

Comment: Si lo se, y no ningún fragmento de código me da problemas, solo quiero añadir esa opción. Pero bueno, mejor doy por cerrada esta pregunta, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Expresión regular:**

```regex
/{([^}]*)}/g
```

**Decripción:**

- `{` - Coincide con una apertura de llave literal
- `([^}]*)` - Grupo 1 - Graba el valor del texto con el que coincidió en una retrorreferencia. Coincide con:

  - `[^}]*` - Cualquier caracter que no sea una `}`, repetido 0 o más veces
- `}` - Coincide con un cierre de llave literal

Al estar utilizando un grupo (con los paréntesis), el resultado de [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), será un array con toda la coincidencia en el índice 0, y el resultado del primer grupo en el índice 1 (o más si usáramos más grupos).

**Código:**

```js
const texto = "{#f66} o {red}",
      regex = /{([^}]*)}/g;
var grupos;

while ((grupos = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
  console.log("Llaves:", grupos[0], "\tPosición:", grupos.index, "\tColor:", grupos[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para atom y poder saber si esta bien tu sintaxis en JavaScript tenes jslint
Para el tema de los colores tenes otro plugin para Atom que se llama color-picker. Podes encontrarlos al buscar en Atom

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, quieres detectar el valor que hay dentro de las llaves, lo que puedes hacer es usar una expresión regular y el método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) que detecte la llave de apertura `{`, lea lo que hay dentro (poniéndolo en un paréntesis) y luego la llave de cierre `{`.

Algo como esto `/{(.*)}/` que puedes ver aquí:

```js
var aux = "{#f00}";

var color = aux.match(/{(.*)}/);

console.log(color);
```

Eso te devolverá un array con la cadena que cumplió la condición y el valor dentro de las llaves.

Comment: Si algo algo así, lo quiero lograr es lo que digo en esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35437/cómo-extender-marked-para-soportar-colores-en-sintaxis

Comment: Para poder darle color al texto, ya sea en negrita, cursiva, links, títulos osea las etiquetas h1, h2, h3, etc.

Comment: Ahora mismo no sé si está pregunta es un duplicado o "spam" para atraer atención a tu otra pregunta.

Comment: No, solo queria saber como pueblor implementar esa opción de la llaves en ese script.

Comment: Pero gracias a ti, ya tengo una idea de como hacerlo. Solo que no se cual es la manera correcta de añadircelo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses la expresión regular de la [solución de Mariano](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36339/250). Es más completa y mejor que la que he compartido. Suerte.

Comment: Ah ok, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Alvaro El tema con esta expresión es que el motor de regex es **[codicioso](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)**, por lo que `.*` intenta coincidir con todo lo que puede (incluyendo múltiples llaves). Para evitarlo, se puede usar `.*?`, que cambia el comportamiento de la repetición, o `[^}]*` (preferible en estos casos)

Comment: @Mariano +1 al comentario (ya te lo di en la respuesta). Cambiaría el código, pero entonces sería igual al tuyo... y estoy algo perezoso esta noche de domingo :P